# Overly verbose output for Teamcity MSBuild Runner

Tags: msbuild, teamcity

I'm kicking of an msbuild script using the Teamcity msbuild runner.

Unfortunately, I'm finding that the build log output is too verbose, specifically each message is prepended with:

[08:52:34]: [Project "SomeScript.msbuild.teamcity.patch.tcprojx" (CleanBuildAll target(s)):]

(The script, teamcity extension, and task being run).

Is there any way to remove this message prefix?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Limitation of Teamcity, their tech support was unable to help me.

The solution is use Hudson instead of Teamcity.